# Concatenate Properties from a System.Data.DataRow object in powershell

Tags: sql-server, string, powershell

I have stored the results of an sql server query in a variable named $TESTER using the Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet.

I want to take the fields from each row (i.e. name, address etc) and concatenate them into a seperate string parameter named $STR

something similar to the below

**$TESTER | Select-Object | ForEach-Object {$STR = $*.name + $*.address + $_.postcode}**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ItemArray property from System.Data.DataRow and join values with a separator.

```
$TESTER | foreach { $STR += $_.ItemArray -join "," }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to concatenate your values, maybe add a separator and add them to a list like so:

```
$data = @()
$TESTER | Select-Object | ForEach-Object { $data += $_.name, $_.address, $_.postcode -join "|" }
```